# Reading bytes from a file with fileinputstream to find lost images

Tags: java, parsing, io, byte

I am trying to read a .raw file to find some "corrupted" images.
I have tried everything.
From my understanding
the following should work

```
public void readFile(){
FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(this.rawFile);
System.out.println(inFile.read());
}
```

but only one byte is printed. I need to read all of them and look for bytes of 255 (signifies the beginning of a new image) and save the bytes from the first 255, until the next 255(the next image) to a .jpg

Sorry if I am not being clear here.

Please ask any questions you may have.

Comment: read() returns an int actually

Comment: @vikiiii: you're incorrect - read() returns the byte read (cast up to an int), or -1 for EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) method on FileInputStream.  This method reads a single byte and returns it.  From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29):

> Reads a byte of data from this input stream. This method blocks if no input is yet available.

You have a couple of alternatives ...

You could continue to read one byte at a time, in which case you need a loop:

```
int read;

while ((read = inFile.read()) != -1)
{
  // process the byte
}
```

Alternatively, you could read a chunk of the file into a buffer and iterate over the buffer using [`read(byte[],int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29).

If the file isn't too big, you could read it into memory in one go.

```
final byte[] buff = new byte[this.rawFile.length()];    // size the array
inFile.read(buff);                                      // read the whole file in
inFile.close();                                         // close the file descriptor

for (int i = 0; i < buff.length; i++)                   // search the in-memory buffer
{
  if (buff[i] == 0xFF)
  {
    // found marker byte ...
  }
}
```

Comment: you might want to process the byte by writing it to a ByteArrayOutputStream. This would allow you to save all bytes in one image to one byte[]

Comment: Is it possible to do it with a fileOutputStream?

Comment: Also, I was told JPEG files begin with the bytes 255 216 255 224 (these are the integer formats of the bytes) how would I make the program stop once it finds that sequence?

Comment: @user1304317: simply peek at more bytes in the buffer.  Is this enough for you to keep going?

Comment: well, i cant find the sequence 255 216 255 224 i find them all in different places, not consecutively

Comment: @user1304317: have you opened up the file in a hex editor and looked to see if those marker sequences exist in the file?  Once we know they're really there, then we can start looking for a bug in the code ...

Comment: @user1304317: yes, it doesn't matter how we write it - decimal 255 is hexadecimal 0xFF.  Your sequence in hex is 0xFF 0xD8 0xFF 0xE0.  Do you have a hex editor / viewer?